# Publishing application with ClickOnce and MSI

Tags: wix, windows-installer, clickonce

Our application is currently published via ClickOnce. Till now. Some of our clients requested a MSI package.

Is it possible to support both deployment strategies using the same code and same Visual Studio solution? How would you setup your projects within the solution in order to create clean ClickOnce and MSI packages?

Regards
Paul

Answer (score 0):

It's one or the other, so you'd need to create an installer setup project (and you may need to download and install the installer project add in) and add it to your solution. Your app seems relatively straightforward if it can be deployed with ClickOnce, so you could start here for setup projects, old but still relevant:

https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/visual-studio/getting-started-with-setup-projects/

You could use WiX of course, but it's a steeper learning curve, and you'd need to look at upgrade strategies such as major upgrades.

ClickOnce deployments are per user, MSI can be per system or per user, so that may be a consideration. It *may* be part of the reason clients are asking for MSI files, or it may be that they are deploying with group policy. If it's group policy the general requirement is the MSI can be installed silently without user input.